# iOS 16 - Is there a way to exclude my App from Stage Manager programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, apple-m1, ios16

The app will be displayed in a smaller window, when Stage manager enabled in iPad OS 16.

Apple iPadOS 16 Introduced New feature Stage manager in M1 chip based iPad Pro Devices.

This feature affects my application screen content.

is there anyway to exclude my App from Stage Manager by programmatically, so that app content displayed in Full screen.

UIRequiresFullScreen enabling also not helping

```
UIRequiresFullScreen = YES
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The same here. in capacitor app the height of a view port is displayed incorrectly. I need a way to check if the app is running in stage manager.